# How to keep the scanner from skipping (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As of now, my program completely skips over allowing the user to enter input into the var "runAgain". I understand putting "myScanner.nextLine();" directly after runAgain would fix this problem. However it also requires the user to enter again. I would like to avoid this if possible. Any solutions? Thanks.

```
System.out.print("\nRun #" + count + "? ");
runAgain = myScanner.nextLine();
    if ()  {
        end program;
    }
    else {
        re-run program;
    }
```

Comment: _However it also requires the user to enter again._ What makes you think so? Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: Also, why aren't you using `Arrays.asList()` instead of the awkward, memory-leak-prone double-brace style?

Comment: Leaving [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods?rq=1) here as a potential duplicate target.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried it and that's what happened.

Comment: Is it possible that you used your scanner earlier to read some other token via `next()` or `nextInt()` or other `next*Type*()` method? If that is the case then check [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: @Pshemo I believe that was the problem. I ended up just making two different scanners. One for lines, the other for doubles and integers. Thanks for the help and patience, guys!

Comment: @LouisWasserman could you post a code example for that method? Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: @JonathanMousley are you looking for `List<String> negativeResponse = Arrays.asList("n", "N", "no", "No", "NO", "0");` ?

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes. Thank you!